SFTP setup with multiple users
I am setting up SFTP in a Linux machine. Below are few details on existing folder structure:
/var/home/outbound/
/var/home/outbound/user1
/var/home/outbound/user2
/var/home/outbound/user3

I have created a group sftpusers and added the users 1, 2, and 3. Home directory of each user is as below:
For user1: /var/home/outbound/user1
For user2: /var/home/outbound/user2
For user3: /var/home/outbound/user3

I updated SSHD config file with below details:
Match Group sftpusers
    ChrootDirectory /var/home/outbound
    ForceCommand internal-sftp
    PasswordAuthentication yes
    PermitTunnel no
    AllowAgentForwarding no
    AllowTcpForwarding no
    X11Forwarding no

Each time any user tries to SFTP, they will be landed onto /var/home/outbound folder (as this is set as ChrootDirectory) and will be able to cd into all the folders under outbound directory. But the requirement I have is that, user1 should be able to SFTP into his specific folder - /var/home/outbound/user1 and user2 should be able to SFTP into his specific folder alone - /var/home/outbound/user2 and so on.
I have also tried below options in the SSHD config file:
Option1:
Match Group sftpusers
    ChrootDirectory %h
    ForceCommand internal-sftp
    PasswordAuthentication yes
    PermitTunnel no
    AllowAgentForwarding no
    AllowTcpForwarding no
    X11Forwarding no

Option2:
Match Group sftpusers
    ChrootDirectory /var/home/outound/%u
    ForceCommand internal-sftp
    PasswordAuthentication yes
    PermitTunnel no
    AllowAgentForwarding no
    AllowTcpForwarding no
    X11Forwarding no

In both the cases, I got below error:
fatal: bad ownership or modes for chroot directory "/var/home/outbound/user1" [postauth]
How should my SSHD config file be updated to accommodate this?

%h or %u in ChrootDirectory is the way to go, if you want to totally separate users. Then this answer.

Please do not multi-post. For the record, another copy is on Unix & Linux SE.
